# slow loading when clicked on table view cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

When i click on table view cell, it will be in the same table view for some time(till the next page is completely load) then it will display the next view..

i want on click on the table view cell, it should immediately goto next page and  show the loading page popup..

i have tried with impActivityAgent and also tried to show alert view when it will enter the next page(but view is of previous page ie table view).. but.. its loading the page completely, which will take time and then its showing alert..

in next page i am posting and parsing the data which will take time, during that time i want to show the activity indicator..

i have tried many methods, but still its first loading the next page completely and then displaying the contents or alertView or activity indicator and i am not able to show the activity indicator when clicked on table view cell..

MY CODE:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    nextTableViewController *doc = [[nextTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:doc animated:YES];
}
```

AND NEXT VIEW CONTROLLER IS :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[[ImpActivityAgent defaultAgent] makeBusy:YES];

NSURL *loadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/gmail.com",inputURL]];
htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadUrl];
self.htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self parseHTML];
}
```

and in Parse function i am Parsing the content which i got as response in HTML formate using "hpple" Parser..

Comment: Check any back ground process is going on after u selected the row. Post some relevant code.

Comment: no there is no back groung Process going on..

Comment: @Raju, Post your code

Comment: Post your code for tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and whatever you do in the next controller in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, etc.

Comment: please find the above edited question with code..

Comment: @Raju you are calling webservice in Viewdidload . so when u push your controller then first it will get data from service and after that it will push to next view. so paste your whole code in viewdidappear as per rdelmar's suggesion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one separate thread to handle parsing. Hope this code will help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[[ImpActivityAgent defaultAgent] makeBusy:YES];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(newMethodForParsing) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}


-(void)newMethodForParsing
{
NSURL *loadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/gmail.com",inputURL]];
htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadUrl];
self.htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self parseHTML];

[tableView reload]; // tableView refers to your table view name

}
```

Comment: now im getting what i requires but its not calling "-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" function.. which is present in nextViewController..

Comment: Check now. Updated my answer. U need to reload the table view once parsing is completed.

Comment: @ Ganapathy : how can i stop os cancel or kill this thread on cancel button? i am using "[NSThread cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(newMethodForParsing) object:nil];" but its now working..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[ImpActivityAgent defaultAgent] makeBusy:YES];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(start) withObject:Nil];
    //or you can use after delay then no need to use perform selector on main thread in start method.
    [self performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

-(void)start
{
    NSURL *loadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/gmail.com",inputURL]];
    htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadUrl];
    self.htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parseHTML) withObject:Nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(newMethodForParsing) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)newMethodForParsing
{
NSURL *loadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/gmail.com",inputURL]];
htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadUrl];
self.htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self parseHTML];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ganapathy's answer leaks memory, you need to place an autoreleasepool inside the method. this is a simpler way to do this. this will run on the main thread but after the existing tasks in the queue.

If you want it to run on a different thread replace with `dispatch_get_global_queue()`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   [[ImpActivityAgent defaultAgent] makeBusy:YES];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

      NSURL *loadUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/gmail.com",inputURL]];
      htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:loadUrl];
      self.htmlSTR = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      [self parseHTML];
   )
}
```